# jQuery clone form field till maximum count

Tags: jquery, forms, clone, field

I am allowing user to add more field on click. But I want allow user to add maximum 4 fields. How can I alter this code to make it works. So when user creates total 4 elements than `Add Photo` button should turns to disable mode or hide. I prefer disable but if it is hard than hide also would be fine.

Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('#add-photo-button').click(function(){

        var current_count = jQuery('input[type="file"]').length;
        var next_count = current_count + 1;

        jQuery('#file-upload').prepend('<input type="file" name="photo_' + next_count + '" />');    

   });

});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form id="file-upload" action="#" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="image-uploader-box" class="group">           
        <div id="forms" class="add-photo-fields">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            <input type="button" id="add-photo-button" class="add-photo-button" value="Add Photo"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/alejak/2)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $cnt = 1;
  jQuery('#add-photo-button').click(function(){
   if($cnt == 4){
     //$('#add-photo-button').hide();
     $('#add-photo-button').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   $cnt++;
   var current_count = jQuery('input[type="file"]').length;
   var next_count = current_count + 1;
   jQuery('#file-upload').prepend('<input type="file" name="photo_' + next_count + '"  />');    

 });

});
```

Comment: Wonderful! working perfectly. Just one small question how can I change class of the button when disabled?

Comment: Ah! simple I used addClass thanks a lot everything is fine now. Answer selected

Comment: you can use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)